# Convert HTTP Header timestamp to another datetime format

Tags: javascript, php, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

in my client-server communications (javascript based) I am getting some headers, on of which is

```
Date : Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:35:31 GMT
```

but I need to convert it to epoch time and also to this type of format which my PHP app understands:

```
2013-07-26 21:36:51
```

I tried to look at Javascript Date object reference but cant find away to convert from one date format to the other in Javascript. I am also unsure about the official names of each of my specified date/time formats.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need it in PHP or in JavaScript. Here my solutions:

```js
var newDate = new Date("Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:35:31 GMT");

newDateString =
    newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+
    (newDate.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (newDate.getMonth()+1) : (newDate.getMonth()+1))  +"-"+
    (newDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + newDate.getDate() : newDate.getDate())  +" "+
    (newDate.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + newDate.getHours() : newDate.getHours())+":"+
    (newDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + newDate.getMinutes() : newDate.getMinutes())+":"+
    (newDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + newDate.getSeconds() : newDate.getSeconds());
console.log(newDateString);
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyper/8SUZs/).

PHP-Solution:

```php
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:35:31 GMT"));
```

You can test it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kzeyo4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a date object before you can print it out in another format. Therefore you need to parse the string and get its constituent parts. A regular expression will work here:

```
var string = "Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:35:31 GMT"
var parts = string.match(/(\w*), (\d{2}) (\w*) (\d{4}) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/);
var month = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(parts[3]) / 3 + 1
td = new Date(parts[4], month, parts[2],parts[5], parts[6], parts[7])
td.getTime()
```

Comment: awesome, thanks, I wish I could choose two answers as correct. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your application has some flexibility as to where the conversion happens, a simple way to do it would be to convert the date string to a unix timestamp in JavaScript then convert the unix timestamp to the necessary format in PHP.

### JavaScript

Convert date string into a unix timestamp in GMT timezone:

```
var unixTimestamp = new Date('Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:35:31 GMT')/1000
```

### PHP

Convert unix timestamp into the appropriate date format:

```
$result = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

### Result

```
2014-03-04 21:35:31
```